# How can I position my logo correctly?

Tags: html, css

EDIT:
The chat window should be aligned to the right, with the chat area within the chat window, like this, why isn't it?: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Robinlemon/pen/dMzeoq)

Should be this:
[image]

---

I'm looking to make a simple site with a header and a rectangle on the side. For some reason, I cannot position my logo correctly! What I currently have:

```css
html,
body {
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background: #ccc;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right top, #8900AB, #282828);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top right, #8900AB, #282828);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top right, #8900AB, #282828);
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #8900AB, #282828);
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    background: #404040;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://csgovoid.net/img/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Seperator_H01"></div>
    
    <div id="chat_extended">
        <div id="chat_area"></div>
        <input id="chat_input" type="text" placeholder="Chat...">
        <button id="send_button" onClick="send()">SEND</buttton>
    </div>
    <div id="Seperator_V01"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Robinlemon/pen/dMzeoq)

What I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

(The text input and send button aren't included in the picture.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to add a width and height :) A div has a height and width of zero by default, and since there is nothing in there you need to set it!

Comment: The header has a width and height and the logo is inside, so shouldn't the logo adjust itself to fit? I was previously using the img tag but the logo wouldn't scale to fit the div.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain better! Your logo div technically has nothing in it. It has a background image, but the background image wont show if there is no width or height :) Glad I could help!

Comment: Don't forget to mark as correct if this solved your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle  : https://jsfiddle.net/5odd0q1n/

CSS :

```
html,
body {
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background: #ccc;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right top, #8900AB, #282828);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top right, #8900AB, #282828);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top right, #8900AB, #282828);
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #8900AB, #282828);
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    background: #404040;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(http://csgovoid.net/img/logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height:100%;
}
```

HTML : (you had a typo in `</button>`)

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Seperator_H01"></div>

    <div id="chat_extended">
        <div id="chat_area"></div>
        <input id="chat_input" type="text" placeholder="Chat...">
        <button id="send_button" onClick="send()">SEND</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Seperator_V01"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Absoulute position is not good for responsivnes becuse you can't get a width or a height relative to parrent using css only :)

Anyways you asked for border line on the header : https://jsfiddle.net/5odd0q1n/3/ (you can find it here)

you only need to add

```
border-bottom: 10px solid purple ;
```

to your `#header` :)

Comment: Whilst your here, I need a purple line beneath that grey header box, so I tried using 'margin-top: 10%' because the header height is 10%, the line being 1% but this puts the div at the bottom of the screen! [link](http://codepen.io/Robinlemon/pen/dMzeoq)

Comment: The line is incorrectly placed, it should lie just in between the grey box and the gradient area.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add img tag;

```
<div id="logo">
<img src="http://csgovoid.net/img/logo.png">
</div>

and add following css:

#logo img{
   width:2%;
    //background stuff is removed -- not required in this case

}

#chat_extended
{   text-align:center;
    padding-top:5%;
}

#header {
    position: absolute;
    background: #404040;
    width: 100%;
 //height is removed -- not required
}
```

Comment: But if the image doesn't load it produces a terrible box! The height is also required because the logo is 600x600px

Comment: dont use absolute positioning untill and unless its outer div ha position of relative -- good practice

Comment: logo will get adjusted as per div is set

Comment: you only need to mention width

Comment: good advice here as it's horizontal layout is acctualy to specify height :) and width will self adjust , and one more thing that's good is to use background image for that logo, because background images are parsed separate from file :)